# excel to pdf using .net

Tags: .net, excel, pdf

the input for my .net web application is an excel work book. A work book will have more than one work sheet. Each sheet will have the salary information of each employee. When the employees want to access their salary details, the relevant sheet should be taken from the excel and displayed in PDF format. Is it possible to do this task? Please guide me.

Comment: It is possible, but any special reason for doing it that way?  This will be better using a database

Comment: Even when using a database (which is a suggestion I definitely support), that does not solve the problem of getting the salary information to a well-formatted PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going to do this on a server, you should definitely avoid the Excel-Automation-Print-To-File-Convert-To-Pdf route. Best option in your case IMHO is using a third party library which supports your needs like this one:

[Excel to PDF .NET](http://www.sautinsoft.com/)

(Any free .NET libraries I know for accessing Excel sheets without Excel do not support printing or converting to PDF).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't help for the reading of Excel files but if you want you can want to generate a PDF use free libraries from C# you can use [iTextSharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/itextsharp) or use [XSL Formatting objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) to do it with a transform.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [PDF Converter Services](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html). It can pretty much convert any modern format using a web services interface and works perfect in server based environments. It also does other things including watermarking and securing PDF files if you need it.

I worked on the application so the usual disclaimers apply.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [This One](http://www.sautinsoft/convert-excel-xls-to-pdf/spreadsheet-xls-excel-to-pdf-export-component-asp.net.php)

```
//Export to PDF
            var x = new SautinSoft.ExcelToPdf{OutputFormat = SautinSoft.ExcelToPdf.eOutputFormat.Pdf};
            var pdfpath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.pdf", currentDirectorypath, fileName);
           x.ConvertFile(localXcelPath, pdfpath);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following is what I ended up using:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\folder\file.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
```

Translated to VB.NET of course.